# Opposite (antonym) of peak hour / time

Tags: antonyms

I am looking for a conventional antonym for *peak hour*.

As far as I've seen, the term *off-peak hours* is used. Still, to me this means any hour that is not the peak hour, which is not necessarily the hour with the least clients or activity in a business.

Here is an example sentence:

> Eight o'clock till nine o'clock is our peak hour; two o'clock till three o'clock is our _____.

Can anybody please help with this?

Comment: I'm guessing "slowest hour" is not colorful enough?

Answer (score 5):

Consider *slack* (["wanting in activity"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slack)).

> Two o'clock till three o'clock is our slack period.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "lull" period which is the slowest time in activities of an establishment.

Comment: Answers should contain definition and it source, for questions like the this one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit klunky, but I've seen **doldrums** used this way before:

> A state or period of inactivity, stagnation, or slump ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doldrums))

Comment: What catches me is that M-W calls doldrums a plural noun, yet it's defined as "**a** state or period".  So I'm perplexed whether it would be " two o'clock till three o'clock **is\are** our doldrums.